# ec2 ami device mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have large ec2 Ubuntu image and I'm just looking through the devices.

I noticed from the metadata that

```
%  curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ami
sda1
%  curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ephemeral0
sdb
```

However when I look what is actually mounted there is `/dev/xvda1` and `/dev/xvdb`  (and there is no `/dev/sd*` )

I know that both names look somewhat valid from the AWS documentation, but it looks to me from this like there is a mismatch in the instance metadata and what is actually on the machine.

Why don't they match?

Answer (score 0):

If you do an `ls -la` in /dev you'll see that sda1 links to xvda1

```
$ ls -la sd*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Oct 26 15:54 sda1 -> xvda1
```

Comment: Small note: on recently launched instances [at least mine] there are no symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Newer kernels are making these devices (at least under Xen virtualization) appear with names xvdN instead of sdN.  Everyone has adapted.